# Is it allowed and accepted to mark a static method with delete?

Tags: c++, static, crtp

Assume for all business object an interface is designed to hide the implementation. PIMPL pattern is not in use.

```
class CNetworkManager : public IMyNetwork {...};
```

All of these managers are singletons with methods like:

NetworkManager.h

```
CNetworkManager* CNetworkManager::getInstance();
CNetworkManager* CNetworkManager::destroy();
```

But NetworkManager.h is not exported. Thus static methods are used within

NetworkManagerFactory.h

```
class CMyNetworkFactory
{
    public:
        static IMyNetwork* getInstance();
        static void destroy();
};
```

NetworkManagerFactory.cpp

```
IMyNetwork* CMyNetworkFactory::getInstance()
{
    return CNetworkManager::getInstance();
}
```

But all factories should use the same naming. Thus I added

Template ISingletonFactory.h

```
template <class Factory, class Interface>
class CSingletonFactory
{
    public:
        ~CSingletonFactory() {}
        static Interface* getInstance() = delete;
        static void destroy() = delete;
};
```

and reworked NetworkManagerFactory.h to CRTP

```
class CMyNetworkFactory : public CSingletonFactory<CMyNetworkFactory, IMyNetwork>
{
    public:
        static IMyNetwork* getInstance();
        static void destroy();
};
```

Questions: Is the usage of **static** together with **delete** bad as possible or common art?

Comment: what is the reason for all factories being required to have the same methods declared? THere is not much you can do with the deleted `getInstance` (other than creating compiler errors)

Comment: What's wrong with just not declaring them?

Comment: Typically `= delete` is to tell the compiler not to synthesize the routine, which would otherwise be synthesized by the compiler.  Some devs put in `= delete` on routines which the compiler would not synthesize, to explicitly inform the follow-up developer that it isn't there (but it turns out that can cause some problems, too, since implicitly not synthesized is not the same as explicitly not synthesized; when the problem crops up it is very obvious though).

Comment: "bad as possible" no, it could be worse ;). Its just not clear what is the motivation to do so. I would not leave it like that but at least add a comment

Answer (score 1):

> Is the usage of static and delete bad as possible or common art?

`= delete;` is a function definition strictly speaking. Any function may therefore be defined as deleted. The function being a member or free, static or not, is completely orthogonal to the deleted definition.

The consequence of deleting, is that a program that refers to the deleted function becomes ill-formed. The referral is determined by overload resolution.

So yes, it's common practice to delete a definition if we want to prohibit something. You seem to wish to prevent something like `CMyNetworkFactory` to be defined without a `getInstance`. But then I confess to not seeing why you need to define anything as deleted via a CRTP. After all, name lookup failing to find `getInstance` entirely is just as good as it resolving to a deleted definition, I think.

Comment: The aim using CRTP is to force to implement the static methods. Non-static is not possible because there is no instance.